# getElement by position?

Tags: javascript, svg, element

I am working on SVG script

there are getElementById or getElementsByTagName

but I can't find any method to get elements by position

such as get the elements whose position is x=10,y=10.

is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259585/get-element-at-specified-position-javascript

Comment: Another possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174640/hit-testing-svg-shapes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var yourElement = document.elementFromPoint(10, 10);
```

Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/nBhAA/4/) that changes the background colour of the element at the specified point.

Note that if the specified point is outside the *visible* area of the document, `elementFromPoint` will return `null`.

Comment: thanks! but it seems returns only one element. right? I want to get every element take up in 10,10 any suggestion? do I have to use jquery as ShankarSangoli said?

Comment: Ohh sorry I see... then yes I think jQuery will be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("svg").find("[x='10'][y='10']");
```

It will give all the elements with svg which have x = 10 and y = 10.

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XkPTc/1/)

Comment: I see, my bad :). But it would help OP a lot if he starts using jquery.

Comment: @Shankar - No need for jQuery in this case. See my answer.

Comment: thank you! but it seems doesn't works for line whose coordinate is not 10,10 but take up 10,10. any ideas?

Comment: @kim - You want to find elements whose position is 10,10 right? Thats what it will give you.

Comment: This method won't work if element is transformed by any means. Additionally, OP _probably_ wanted hit-testing, you're suggesting checking origin instead.

Answer (score -1):

see this implementation

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-50184.html