# mouse over two elements at same position

Tags: jquery, css, svg

Can I detect if the mouse is over two elements at same position?
I have two circles and I would like do something if the mouse is over a mutual part of them. Some tricks can be done via CSS as well as jQuery.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Coffee SVG</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #coffee-svg > rect {
            fill: #c3c99f;
        }

        #coffee-svg circle:hover {
            opacity: 1;
        }

        #ingredients #coffe {
            fill: #330a0a;
        }
        #ingredients #milk {
            fill: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <svg id="coffee-svg" width="500" height="600">
        <!-- Background -->
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" />
        
        <g id="ingredients">
            <!-- Coffee -->
            <circle id="coffe" cx="250" cy="250" r="90" opacity="0.8" />
            <!-- Milk -->
            <circle id="milk" cx="250" cy="160" r="70" opacity="0.8" />
        </g>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** I will add few circles more and I would detect various combinations of them. So @RodrigoQuiñonesPichioli answer is not useful for me.

Comment: how can you hover over 2 elements at the same time!!??

Comment: @kukkuz The elements overlap, and you're in that part of them.

Comment: @Barmar but one of the 2 will be on top and only that will be hovered right?

Comment: You are rigth. I'm asking about can I detect if mouse over element that is under first one?

Comment: mouse hover only applies to the top layer. If you want to detect it, you need to calculate by coordinates.

Comment: Doesn't it help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377443/detecting-mouse-events-on-multiple-overlapping-svg-elements ?

Comment: @MikelisBaltruks Is there easy way?

Comment: @VadymPerepeliak so in the demo you have given you want both hover styles to be applied on hover on the overlapping part?

Comment: I am not experienced, but I am trying to figure one out. xD

Comment: @VadymPerepeliak I was trying to calculate mathematically if you are over both (by coordinates), but doing that on every move is too much. Algorithm for that is - if mouse coordinate is less or equal distance from both circle centers then their radiuses.     Or another (stupid way). On every mousemove "remember" what was the last element hovered. If previous was circle A and now is on circle B (or vice-versa), you are on overlaying part. But that can really glitch.

Comment: I foundsolution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377443/detecting-mouse-events-on-multiple-overlapping-svg-elements?noredirect=1&lq=1). Here is the [jsfiddle](`http://jsfiddle.net/michaschwab/w0wufbtn/13/`) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my purpose I use native javascript function `document.elementsFromPoint`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not capable of coming up with an algo to do this but here's a poor man's method.

```js
$('.left-over-circle, .right-over-circle').hover(
  function() {
    $('.left-over-circle, .right-over-circle').css('background-color', 'red');
  }, 
  function() {
    $('.left-over-circle, .right-over-circle').css('background-color', 'white');
  }
);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;  height: 200px; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.left-under, .right-under {
  position: absolute;
   top: 0;
  width: 200px;  height: 200px;
}
.left-under {
  left: 0;
  background-color: pink;
 }
.right-under {
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
 }
.left-under-circle, .right-under-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;  height: 150px;
  top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: black;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
.left-under-circle {
  right: -20%;
}
.right-under-circle {
  left: -20%;
}

.left-over, .right-over {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 200px;  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 13;
}
.left-over {
  left: 0;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.2);
 }
.right-over {
  right: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.2);
 }
.left-over-circle, .right-over-circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;  height: 150px;
  top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.left-over-circle {
  right: -55%;
}
.right-over-circle {
  left: -55%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left-under">
    <div class="left-under-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-under">
    <div class="right-under-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="left-over">
    <div class="left-over-circle"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-over">
    <div class="right-over-circle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/z12tgedz/

Comment: It is nice solution. I may use it