# How to generate points with random positions inside a polygon? (d3.js)

Tags: d3.js

I am making a map with some countries and I would like to draw points which are randomly position inside those countries. I was trying to use bounding box, but the points were  very often  drawn outside the country.

I have found the point-in-polygon function http://bl.ocks.org/bycoffe/5575904

It checks if the point intersects with some line coordinates and I don't know how to get those from my map.

Regards,
Almbu

Comment: It may be easier to generate random points in the bounding box and discard those that are not within the actual shape.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Lars Kotthoff. I am able to generate the points in the bounding box. I can read the bounds, and then I generate new position based on those bounds values.

But I don't know how to figure out which one are within the actual shape.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2174640/hit-testing-svg-shapes) has a few hints on that.

Comment: It seems that getIntersectionList is not supported in all browsers. Is there any other way?

Comment: Yes, have a look at the second answer.